# Problema con consulta, subqueries, join y doctrine2 en symfony4

Tags: php, sql, symfony, symfony4, doctrine

Tengo una entidad llamada **User**, que justamente representa a un usuario y otra entidad llamada **Friendship** para establacer la relación de amistad entre dos usuario.

La entidad **Friendship** es la siguiente:

```
class Friendship
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user1;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user2;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener los amigos en comun entre dos amigos, esto lo puedo hacer en una consulta sql, de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT user.* FROM
    user,
    (
        (
            SELECT user.id FROM friendship,user
                WHERE
                    (friendship.user1_id = user.id and friendship.user2_id = '1') or (friendship.user2_id = user.id and friendship.user1_id = '1')
        ) as u1
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT user.id FROM friendship,user
                WHERE
                    (friendship.user1_id = user.id and friendship.user2_id = '2') or (friendship.user2_id = user.id and friendship.user1_id = '2')
        ) as u2
    )
    WHERE u1.id = u2.id and user.id = u1.id
    ;
```

La pregunta es ... ¿Como hago esta consulta con doctrine de symfony?

Lo que si puedo hacer es dado un usuario, obtener sus amigos:

```
public function findFriends($user)
{
    $qb = ($this->createQueryBuilder(''))
        ->select('u')
        ->from(User::class, 'u')
        ->from(Friendship::class, 'f')
        ->where('(f.user1 = u and f.user2 = :user) or (f.user2 = u and f.user1 = :user)')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Entonces basandome en esta idea quiero obtener los amigos en comunes, y empece escribiendo lo siguiente:

```
public function findMutualFriends($user1, $user2)
{
    $sub1 = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('u1')
        ->from(User::class, 'u1')
        ->from(Friendship::class, 'f')
        ->where('(f.user1 = u1 and f.user2 = :user1) or (f.user2 = u1 and f.user1 = :user1)')
        ->setParameter('user1', $user1)
        ;

    $sub2 = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('u2.id')
        ->from(User::class, 'u2')
        ->from(Friendship::class, 'f')
        ->where('(f.user1 = u2 and f.user2 = :user2) or (f.user2 = u2 and f.user1 = :user2)')
        ->setParameter('user2', $user2)
        ;
```

Ahora, no se como continuar con la consulta?

Comment: Hola, la idea de usar DQL es poder realizar consultas sql de forma mas simple, en los casos en que se te complique demasiado la solución rápida es enviar la consulta directamente con `prepare()`.

Answer (score 0):

Veo difícil obtener el resultado en una sola consulta, yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

1. Crear dos consultas para extraer los **ids** de los *frienship* de cada usuario.
2. Obtener los ids en común.
3. Extraer los objetos con esos ids.

Primero realizas las dos consultas:

```html
<?php
  $query =  $em->getRepository(User::class)
               ->createQueryBuilder('u')
               ->select('f.id')
               ->innerJoin('u.frienship', 'f')
               ->where('u.id = :userId');
                          
  $fiendship_user_1 = $query->setParameter('userId', $user_1_id)->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
  $fiendship_user_2 = $query->setParameter('userId', $user_2_id)->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
  
  $ids_user_1 = array_column($fiendship_user_1, 'id');
  $ids_user_2 = array_column($fiendship_user_2, 'id');
```

Ahora obtenemos las coincidencias en los arrays (ids en común):

```html
<?php
  $ids_en_comun = array_intersect($ids_user_1, $ids_user_2);
```

Y por último obtienes los usuarios con esos ids:

```html
<?php
  $users = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findBy( array('id' => $ids_en_comun), array('id' => 'DESC') );
```

Esta es mi solución para este caso, aunque creo que no es la mejor, te sirve para obtener el resultado que espetas.

Espero que te sirva.